# Ways to change ArcMap 10 editing tool back to ArcMap 9.3 version

Tags: arcgis-10.0, tools, editing, toolbar

I'm trying to get used to using ArcGIS 10, but in the meantime I still need to actually get work done.  I stumbled across a way to change the editor tool from its 10 version back to the 9.3 version (with the drop-down task bar etc).  Now I can't find out ow to do it anywhere, -1 internet for me.

Can anyone can give me the steps to change the editor toolbar back to the 9.3 version?

Answer (score 8):

To revert to the ArcGIS 9 editing environment: "The setting is found in the Advanced ArcMap Settings utility, located in the \Utilities directory where you installed ArcGIS." From http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reverting_to_the_ArcGIS_9_editing_environment/001t00000013000000/

Answer (score 5):

The answer on this question might also help: [ArcGIS Desktop 10 Tips and Tricks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/arcgis-desktop-10-tips-and-tricks/2024#2024)

> If you prefer the old method, you can
>   revert by setting by running
>   ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Utilities\AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe,
>   clicking the Editor tab, and
>   unchecking Create features using
>   templates and restarting ArcMap.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To edit data, you need to add the Editor toolbar to ArcMap by clicking the Editor Toolbar button on the **Standard** toolbar.

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_editing/001t00000002000000/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much - I knew it was somewhere around Utilities, but I couldn't seem to find quite the right place.  In the meantime, I can still toy around with the new editor toolbar layout but still get my work done.  Thanks a bunch!