# Python coding question, looping through feature classes, AddField, CalculateField, then errors (might be schema lock)

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, error, large-datasets

This is not a SDE question. File GDB.

I have a general question on looping through feature classes in a file geodatabase. I have (attached) a python script that adds a ton of fields and calculates them. It seems to run okay for 2-3 feature classes but by the time it hits the 4th or 5th one it often breaks down to Error 99999 or a dreaded schema lock error. Then if I comment out the first 2-3 fc's and run it just for 4 and 5 one at a time it runs fine.

Is there some way to 'clear' the loop at the end or should I MakeTableView do everything, export the table, then Delete the TableView? Should I be using environments too instead of using the long paths?

I don't have many people look at my code and have no real training so if there are any very very obvious things I'm doing wrong please let me know.

```
import arcpy, time, datetime, csv
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True

calcfiles = [
"E:/SpiderOak/projects/streetview/pedestrian_safety/processing/tables/census_joins.gdb/nyc_0250m_census",
"E:/SpiderOak/projects/streetview/pedestrian_safety/processing/tables/census_joins.gdb/nyc_1000m_census",
"E:/SpiderOak/projects/streetview/pedestrian_safety/processing/tables/census_joins.gdb/phi_0250m_census",
"E:/SpiderOak/projects/streetview/pedestrian_safety/processing/tables/census_joins.gdb/phi_1000m_census",
"E:/SpiderOak/projects/streetview/pedestrian_safety/processing/tables/census_joins.gdb/saj_0250m_census",
"E:/SpiderOak/projects/streetview/pedestrian_safety/processing/tables/census_joins.gdb/saj_1000m_census"
]

prefld = ["hkq",
"hk1",
"hkq",
"hk1",
"hkq",
"hk1"
]

print 'Calc Apportioned Census Loop started at this time: ' + time.strftime('%c') 

for cfname, prefieldname in zip(calcfiles, prefld):   
      cenvar = [
            "totpop",         #'!SET001001!*!pctorgarea!', #Total Population

            "sbatot",         #'!SET005001!*!pctorgarea!', #Total Population:

            "sbamal",         #'!SET005002!*!pctorgarea!',   #Male:
            "sbam05",         #'!SET005003!*!pctorgarea!',         # Under 5 Years
            "sbam09",         #'!SET005004!*!pctorgarea!',         #5 to 9 Years
            "sbam14",         #'!SET005005!*!pctorgarea!',         #10 to 14 Years
            "sbam17",         #'!SET005006!*!pctorgarea!',         #15 to 17 Years
            "sbam24",         #'!SET005007!*!pctorgarea!',         #18 to 24 Years
            "sbam34",         #'!SET005008!*!pctorgarea!',         #25 to 34 Years
            "sbam44",         #'!SET005009!*!pctorgarea!',         #35 to 44 Years
            "sbam54",         #'!SET005010!*!pctorgarea!',         #45 to 54 Years
            "sbam64",         #'!SET005011!*!pctorgarea!',         #55 to 64 Years
            "sbam74",         #'!SET005012!*!pctorgarea!',         #65 to 74 Years
            "sbam84",         #'!SET005013!*!pctorgarea!',         #75 to 84 Years
            "sbamel",         #'!SET005014!*!pctorgarea!',         #85 Years and over

            "sbafem",         #'!SET005015!*!pctorgarea!',   #Female:
            "sbaf05",         #'!SET005016!*!pctorgarea!',         #Under 5 Years
            "sbaf09",         #'!SET005017!*!pctorgarea!',         #5 to 9 Years
            "sbaf14",         #'!SET005018!*!pctorgarea!',         #10 to 14 Years
            "sbaf17",         #'!SET005019!*!pctorgarea!',         #15 to 17 Years
            "sbaf24",         #'!SET005020!*!pctorgarea!',         #18 to 24 Years
            "sbaf34",         #'!SET005021!*!pctorgarea!',         #25 to 34 Years
            "sbaf44",         #'!SET005022!*!pctorgarea!',         #35 to 44 Years
            "sbaf54",         #'!SET005023!*!pctorgarea!',         #45 to 54 Years
            "sbaf64",         #'!SET005024!*!pctorgarea!',         #55 to 64 Years
            "sbaf74",         #'!SET005025!*!pctorgarea!',         #65 to 74 Years
            "sbaf84",         #'!SET005026!*!pctorgarea!',         #75 to 84 Years
            "sbafel",         #'!SET005027!*!pctorgarea!',         #85 Years and over

            "ractot",         #'!SET013001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Total Population:
            "racwht",         #'!SET013002!*!pctorgarea!',      #White Alone
            "racblk",         #'!SET013003!*!pctorgarea!',      #Black or African American Alone
            "racnat",         #'!SET013004!*!pctorgarea!',      #American Indian and Alaska Native Alone
            "racasn",         #'!SET013005!*!pctorgarea!',      #Asian Alone
            "racpac",         #'!SET013006!*!pctorgarea!',      #Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone
            "racotr",         #'!SET013007!*!pctorgarea!',      #Some Other Race Alone
            "ractwo",         #'!SET013008!*!pctorgarea!',      #Two or More races

            "histot",      #'!SET014001*!pctorgarea!',    #Total Population
            "hisnoh",      #'!SET014002*!pctorgarea!',      #Not Hispanic or Latino:
            "hisnwh",      #'!SET014003*!pctorgarea!',          #White Alone
            "hisnbl",      #'!SET014004*!pctorgarea!',          #Black or African American Alone
            "hisnna",      #'!SET014005*!pctorgarea!',          #American Indian and Alaska Native Alone
            "hisnas",      #'!SET014006*!pctorgarea!',          #Asian Alone
            "hisnpa",      #'!SET014007*!pctorgarea!',          #Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone
            "hisntr",      #'!SET014008*!pctorgarea!',          #Some Other Race Alone
            "hisntw",      #'!SET014009*!pctorgarea!',          #Two or More races
            "hisyes",      #'!SET014010*!pctorgarea!',       #Hispanic or Latino:
            "hisywh",      #'!SET014011*!pctorgarea!',          #White Alone
            "hisybl",      #'!SET014012*!pctorgarea!',          #Black or African American Alone
            "hisyna",      #'!SET014013*!pctorgarea!',          #American Indian and Alaska Native Alone
            "hisyas",      #'!SET014014*!pctorgarea!',          #Asian Alone
            "hisypa",      #'!SET014015*!pctorgarea!',          #Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone
            "hisytr",      #'!SET014016*!pctorgarea!',          #Some Other Race Alone
            "hisytw",      #!SET014017*!pctorgarea!',          #Two or More races

            "edutot",         #'!SET025001*!pctorgarea!',   #Population 25 Years and over:
            "edulhs",         #'!SET025002*!pctorgarea!',      #Less Than High School
            "eduhsg",         #'!SET025003*!pctorgarea!',      #High School Graduate (includes equivalency)
            "edusoc",         #'!SET025004*!pctorgarea!',      #Some college
            "edubac",         #'!SET025005*!pctorgarea!',      #Bachelor's degree
            "edumas",         #'!SET025006*!pctorgarea!',      #Master's degree
            "eduprf",         #'!SET025007*!pctorgarea!',      #Professional school degree
            "edudoc",         #'!SET025008*!pctorgarea!',      #Doctorate degree

            "emptot",         #'!SET037001*!pctorgarea!',   #Civilian Population In Labor Force 16 Years And Over:
            "empemp",         #'!SET037002*!pctorgarea!',      #Employed
            "empune",         #'!SET037003*!pctorgarea!',      #Unemployed

            "medhhi",         #'!SET057001!',                     #Median household income (In 2010 Inflation Adjusted Dollars)

            "pastot",         #'!SET080001*!pctorgarea!',   #Households:
            "paswit",         #'!SET080002*!pctorgarea!',      #With public assistance income
            "pasnpu",         #'!SET080003*!pctorgarea!',      #No public assistance income

            "housun",         #'!SET093001*!pctorgarea!',    #Housing units

            "tentot",         #'!SET094001*!pctorgarea!',   #Occupied Housing Units:
            "tenown",         #'!SET094002*!pctorgarea!',      #Owner Occupied
            "tenren",         #'!SET094003*!pctorgarea!',      #Renter Occupied

            "occtot",         #'!SET095001*!pctorgarea!',   #Housing units:
            "occocc",         #'!SET095002*!pctorgarea!',     #Occupied
            "occvac",         #'!SET095003*!pctorgarea!',     #Vacant

            "grttot",         #'!SET102001*!pctorgarea!',   #Renter-occupied housing units with cash rent:
            "grtl03",         #'!SET102002*!pctorgarea!',      #Less than $300
            "grtl06",         #'!SET102003*!pctorgarea!',      #$300 to $599
            "grtl08",         #'!SET102004*!pctorgarea!',      #$600 to $799
            "grtl10",         #'!SET102005*!pctorgarea!',      #$800 to $999
            "grtl12",         #'!SET102006*!pctorgarea!',      #$1,000 to $1,249
            "grtl15",         #'!SET102007*!pctorgarea!',      #$1,250 to $1,499
            "grtl20",         #'!SET102008*!pctorgarea!',      #$1,500 to $1,999
            "grta20",         #'!SET102009*!pctorgarea!',      #$2,000 or More

            "rntmed",         #'!SET104001!',   #Median Gross Rent

            "povtot",         #'!SET113001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Families:
            "povpov",         #'!SET113002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Income in 2010 below poverty level:
            "povcwc",         #'!SET113003!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Married Couple Family: With Related Child Living  Bellow Poverty Level
            "povcnc",         #'!SET113004!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Married Couple Family: No related children under 18 Years
            "povmal",         #'!SET113005!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Male Householder, no wife present:
            "povmwc",         #'!SET113006!*!pctorgarea!',      #            With related children under 18 Years
            "povmnc",         #'!SET113007!*!pctorgarea!',      #            No related children under 18 Years
            "povfem",         #'!SET113008!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Female Householder, no husband present:
            "povfwc",         #'!SET113009!*!pctorgarea!',      #            With related children under 18 Years
            "povnoc",         #'!SET113010!*!pctorgarea!',      #            No related children under 18 Years
            "povabv",         #'!SET113011!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Income In 2010 at or above poverty level

            "trnw16",         #'!SET128001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Workers 16 Years and over:
            "trncar",         #'!SET128002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Car, truck, or van
            "trntax",         #'!SET128003!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Public transportation (Includes Taxicab)
            "trnmot",         #'!SET128004!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Motorcycle
            "trnbik",         #'!SET128005!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Bicycle
            "trnwlk",         #'!SET128006!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Walked
            "trnotr",         #'!SET128007!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Other means
            "trnhom",         #'!SET128008!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Worked at home

            "timw16",         #'!SET129001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Workers 16 Years and over:
            "timwka",         #'!SET129002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Did not work at home:
            "timu10",         #'!SET129003!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Less than 10 minutes
            "timu20",         #'!SET129004!*!pctorgarea!',      #         10 to 19 minutes
            "timu30",         #'!SET129005!*!pctorgarea!',      #         20 to 29 minutes
            "timu40",         #'!SET129006!*!pctorgarea!',      #         30 to 39 minutes
            "timu60",         #'!SET129007!*!pctorgarea!',      #         40 to 59 minutes
            "timu90",         #'!SET129008!*!pctorgarea!',      #         60 to 89 minutes
            "tim90p",         #'!SET129009!*!pctorgarea!',      #         90 or More minutes
            "timhom",         #'!SET129010!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Worked at home

            "nattot",         #'!SET133001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Total Population:
            "natnat",         #'!SET133002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Native Born
            "natfor",         #'!SET133003!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Foreign Born:
            "natntz",         #'!SET133004!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Naturalized Citizen
            "natnoc",         #'!SET133005!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Not a Citizen

            "ownocc",         #'!SET142001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Owner-occupied housing units
            ]

      varexp = [
            '!SET001001!*!pctorgarea!', #Total Population

            '!SET005001!*!pctorgarea!', #Total Population:

            '!SET005002!*!pctorgarea!',   #Male:
            '!SET005003!*!pctorgarea!',         # Under 5 Years
            '!SET005004!*!pctorgarea!',         #5 to 9 Years
            '!SET005005!*!pctorgarea!',         #10 to 14 Years
            '!SET005006!*!pctorgarea!',         #15 to 17 Years
            '!SET005007!*!pctorgarea!',         #18 to 24 Years
            '!SET005008!*!pctorgarea!',         #25 to 34 Years
            '!SET005009!*!pctorgarea!',         #35 to 44 Years
            '!SET005010!*!pctorgarea!',         #45 to 54 Years
            '!SET005011!*!pctorgarea!',         #55 to 64 Years
            '!SET005012!*!pctorgarea!',         #65 to 74 Years
            '!SET005013!*!pctorgarea!',         #75 to 84 Years
            '!SET005014!*!pctorgarea!',         #85 Years and over

            '!SET005015!*!pctorgarea!',   #Female:
            '!SET005016!*!pctorgarea!',         #Under 5 Years
            '!SET005017!*!pctorgarea!',         #5 to 9 Years
            '!SET005018!*!pctorgarea!',         #10 to 14 Years
            '!SET005019!*!pctorgarea!',         #15 to 17 Years
            '!SET005020!*!pctorgarea!',         #18 to 24 Years
            '!SET005021!*!pctorgarea!',         #25 to 34 Years
            '!SET005022!*!pctorgarea!',         #35 to 44 Years
            '!SET005023!*!pctorgarea!',         #45 to 54 Years
            '!SET005024!*!pctorgarea!',         #55 to 64 Years
            '!SET005025!*!pctorgarea!',         #65 to 74 Years
            '!SET005026!*!pctorgarea!',         #75 to 84 Years
            '!SET005027!*!pctorgarea!',         #85 Years and over

            '!SET013001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Total Population:
            '!SET013002!*!pctorgarea!',      #White Alone
            '!SET013003!*!pctorgarea!',      #Black or African American Alone
            '!SET013004!*!pctorgarea!',      #American Indian and Alaska Native Alone
            '!SET013005!*!pctorgarea!',      #Asian Alone
            '!SET013006!*!pctorgarea!',      #Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone
            '!SET013007!*!pctorgarea!',      #Some Other Race Alone
            '!SET013008!*!pctorgarea!',      #Two or More races

            '!SET014001!*!pctorgarea!',    #Total Population
            '!SET014002!*!pctorgarea!',      #Not Hispanic or Latino:
            '!SET014003!*!pctorgarea!',          #White Alone
            '!SET014004!*!pctorgarea!',          #Black or African American Alone
            '!SET014005!*!pctorgarea!',          #American Indian and Alaska Native Alone
            '!SET014006!*!pctorgarea!',          #Asian Alone
            '!SET014007!*!pctorgarea!',          #Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone
            '!SET014008!*!pctorgarea!',          #Some Other Race Alone
            '!SET014009!*!pctorgarea!',          #Two or More races
            '!SET014010!*!pctorgarea!',       #Hispanic or Latino:
            '!SET014011!*!pctorgarea!',          #White Alone
            '!SET014012!*!pctorgarea!',          #Black or African American Alone
            '!SET014013!*!pctorgarea!',          #American Indian and Alaska Native Alone
            '!SET014014!*!pctorgarea!',          #Asian Alone
            '!SET014015!*!pctorgarea!',          #Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander Alone
            '!SET014016!*!pctorgarea!',          #Some Other Race Alone
            '!SET014017!*!pctorgarea!',          #Two or More races

            '!SET025001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Population 25 Years and over:
            '!SET025002!*!pctorgarea!',      #Less Than High School
            '!SET025003!*!pctorgarea!',      #High School Graduate (includes equivalency)
            '!SET025004!*!pctorgarea!',      #Some college
            '!SET025005!*!pctorgarea!',      #Bachelor's degree
            '!SET025006!*!pctorgarea!',      #Master's degree
            '!SET025007!*!pctorgarea!',      #Professional school degree
            '!SET025008!*!pctorgarea!',      #Doctorate degree

            '!SET037001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Civilian Population In Labor Force 16 Years And Over:
            '!SET037002!*!pctorgarea!',      #Employed
            '!SET037003!*!pctorgarea!',      #Unemployed

            '!SET057001!',                      #Median household income (In 2010 Inflation Adjusted Dollars)

            '!SET080001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Households:
            '!SET080002!*!pctorgarea!',      #With public assistance income
            '!SET080003!*!pctorgarea!',      #No public assistance income

            '!SET093001!*!pctorgarea!',    #Housing units

            '!SET094001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Occupied Housing Units:
            '!SET094002!*!pctorgarea!',      #Owner Occupied
            '!SET094003!*!pctorgarea!',      #Renter Occupied

            '!SET095001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Housing units:
            '!SET095002!*!pctorgarea!',     #Occupied
            '!SET095003!*!pctorgarea!',     #Vacant

            '!SET102001!*!pctorgarea!',   #Renter-occupied housing units with cash rent:
            '!SET102002!*!pctorgarea!',      #Less than $300
            '!SET102003!*!pctorgarea!',      #$300 to $599
            '!SET102004!*!pctorgarea!',      #$600 to $799
            '!SET102005!*!pctorgarea!',      #$800 to $999
            '!SET102006!*!pctorgarea!',      #$1,000 to $1,249
            '!SET102007!*!pctorgarea!',      #$1,250 to $1,499
            '!SET102008!*!pctorgarea!',      #$1,500 to $1,999
            '!SET102009!*!pctorgarea!',      #$2,000 or More

            '!SET104001!',                      #Median Gross Rent

            '!SET113001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Families:
            '!SET113002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Income in 2010 below poverty level:
            '!SET113003!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Married Couple Family: With Related Child Living  Bellow Poverty Level
            '!SET113004!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Married Couple Family: No related children under 18 Years
            '!SET113005!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Male Householder, no wife present:
            '!SET113006!*!pctorgarea!',      #            With related children under 18 Years
            '!SET113007!*!pctorgarea!',      #            No related children under 18 Years
            '!SET113008!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Female Householder, no husband present:
            '!SET113009!*!pctorgarea!',      #            With related children under 18 Years
            '!SET113010!*!pctorgarea!',      #            No related children under 18 Years
            '!SET113011!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Income In 2010 at or above poverty level

            '!SET128001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Workers 16 Years and over:
            '!SET128002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Car, truck, or van
            '!SET128003!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Public transportation (Includes Taxicab)
            '!SET128004!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Motorcycle
            '!SET128005!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Bicycle
            '!SET128006!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Walked
            '!SET128007!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Other means
            '!SET128008!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Worked at home

            '!SET129001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Workers 16 Years and over:
            '!SET129002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Did not work at home:
            '!SET129003!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Less than 10 minutes
            '!SET129004!*!pctorgarea!',      #         10 to 19 minutes
            '!SET129005!*!pctorgarea!',      #         20 to 29 minutes
            '!SET129006!*!pctorgarea!',      #         30 to 39 minutes
            '!SET129007!*!pctorgarea!',      #         40 to 59 minutes
            '!SET129008!*!pctorgarea!',      #         60 to 89 minutes
            '!SET129009!*!pctorgarea!',      #         90 or More minutes
            '!SET129010!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Worked at home

            '!SET133001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Total Population:
            '!SET133002!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Native Born
            '!SET133003!*!pctorgarea!',      #      Foreign Born:
            '!SET133004!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Naturalized Citizen
            '!SET133005!*!pctorgarea!',      #         Not a Citizen

            '!SET142001!*!pctorgarea!',      #   Owner-occupied housing units
            ]

      for fname, expre in zip(cenvar, varexp):
            try:
                #arcpy.AddField_management(cfname, fname, "FLOAT")
                #arcpy.CalculateField_management(cfname, fname, expre, "PYTHON")
                arcpy.AddField_management(cfname, prefieldname+fname, "FLOAT")
                arcpy.CalculateField_management(cfname, prefieldname+fname, expre, "PYTHON")
                  # this is with the prefieldname gonna add that later, don't neeed now
                print 'Loop ' + prefieldname + " - field: " + fname + ' done at this time: ' + time.strftime('%c') 
            except:
                print 'Script for ' + cfname + ' screwed up at this time: ' + time.strftime('%c') 

print 'Script ended at this time: ' + time.strftime('%c')
```

Comment: Perhaps something else to ask would be, should I turn this whole thing into a function and then loop through my data to the function, AddCalcCensus(calcfiles,prefld)

Comment: I wonder if the tools are running async, so while it is wrapping up calculatefield for one feature class, it starts on addfield for another. Try doing -only- your AddField operations and see if that works (since AddField is quicker). I would definitely go the function route though.

Comment: Is the rest of your Error 99999 message about "General Function Failure"?

Comment: Could this be a performance issue?  I've had older pc's that made Arcmap cranking with lots of 99999's.  Check [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31699/ways-to-speed-up-python-scripts-running-as-arcgis-tools) .  MakeFeatureLayer and "in_memory" workspace can help streamline.

Comment: @blord-castillo I think your suggestion helps. I tried a version of this in another script (with fewer variables added/calced) and it seemed to not lock up. I will try and modify this code so there's one loop of adding fields and one of calc'ing them. Thanks! I'm pretty new let me know if I didn't vote your comment correctly. I'll also check out in_memory as some people have mentioned that for other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit late to this conversation, but a general comment on the non-arcpy python structure is that you instantiate `cenvar` and `varexp` each time you iterate w/in your `for cfname, prefieldname` loop, which is wasteful. Do it once prior to the loop if it’s not going to change. Also, use `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` in general. Your lists aren’t killer long, but using iterator equivalents of functions is generally good for speed/memory management.

Comment: Oh, so all of that stuff should come before the loop? Thanks. I have been using the comments above and doing the AddField and Calc fields not in the same loop and that helps for adding and calcing many fields. Also, running it as a python file outside of ArcGIS seems to help from errors that may or may not be schema lock related.

Comment: Those comments are good, but are different. I would use them all. I was a little confused by the arcpy part of the conversation because the `AddField()` and `CalculateField()` don't usually leave a lock behind (like a `MakeFeatureLayer()` would), so I wasn't sure how you were ending up with that condition (or thought you were). It would be interesting to know if you got more back from the messaging (like @PolyGeo asked).