# How to add to an existing dataset in Model Builder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I want to run a custom tool created with the Model Builder in ArcGIS.  It needs to output to the SAME file each time it runs, just adding the data.  Basically I have a custom Dissolve tool that will dissolve (in this case) counties together based on user selection.  I need a single file containing ALL the dissolved final shapes, but the Model Builder complains unless each output file is unique. Is there anyway around this or do I have to create dissolve_1, dissolve_2, etc... (to 500 or so) and then combine them afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like the easiest way to accomplish this task is to

1. create a new **empty** output layer/feature class,
2. dissolve the multiple inputs to a scratch (or better yet, an [in_memory](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31699/ways-to-speed-up-python-scripts-running-as-arcgis-tools/31806#31806) layer) and,
3. APPEND or MERGE them together into your designated output file.

Comment: Append was what I was looking for.  Missed it somehow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method to create unique names in Model Builder is to add `%n%` into the output parameter.  In your case, the proper usage would be `dissolve_%n%`

For example

[image]

Or if you would like to create unique names by list position, use `%i%`

[image]

Reference: [Examples of in-line variable substitution with ModelBuilder system variables](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000060000000)

Comment: My understanding of this is that it only works if you use a Loop.  Running the tool multiple unique times would create an error as it resets to 0 (and therefore the name is Buffer0 each time).

Comment: I'm not sure how to get access to this in model builder (it may not be possible), but [Create Unique Name](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004v000000) would solve this issue.

Comment: @Josh, so you need a tool that searches for the last unique name in the run (e.g. dissolve_4) and names the new output "dissolve_5"...?  How about list position %i%?

Comment: That might have worked.  The simplest way to deal with my problem was in the answer by Ryan - append to an already existing file.